# How to decrypt encrypted (SALT) fields in mysql, and then re-encrypt them?

Tags: mysql, salt

I have a cms who use a SALT key in the config file to encrypt / decrypt passwords, credit card and some other sensitive informations in the database.

I would like to decrypt only specific rows in the database using the SALT key, and then re-encrypt the data.

How can i achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: you mean that cms uses a salt and a hash function to encrypt this data? If so, there is no way to decrypt them.

Comment: What CMS are you using? Wordpress? Drupal?

Comment: Hi, the software in question is whmcs.  ...it's ioncube encoded.  All i have is the encryption hash.   Is there something i can try?

Comment: What algorithm was used to transform the passwords?

Comment: Seems like there is a [decrypt function](http://docs.whmcs.com/API:Decrypt_Password) in the documentation. Have you tried that? Btw I hope this is not being used for malicious purposes.

Comment: Ok. thanks.  I'm going to give a try on this.

Comment: There is a difference between hashing (one-way) and encrypting (two-way). Passwords should be hashed using a salt, other data can be encrypted with a key so you can decrypt it later.